# Run .exe file from Powershell from variable

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to read exe file into variable and then Run it from the variable

Here I am showing a pseudocode:

```
$var = Get-Content "d:\projects\powershell\wakeup.exe"
Run $var
```

Comment: Just to clearfy the situation - I need to read the source of the exe into memory and then execute it from memory, Is it possible, though?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @Matt Common malware post-exploitation technique

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Thank you for your comments. I have an idea of using memory for "pretesting" file before writing it onto disk. It is a type of sandboxing. In fact this will allow to create a new technique of avoiding malware appearing on coomputers.                                                                   "Poison used in small proportions cure people"

Comment: @Alex Interesting idea. You might want to take a look [Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection](https://github.com/clymb3r/PowerShell/tree/master/Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection) (the code used in PowerSploit)

Comment: Was looking for the same thing for a while, even wrote some code myself but every tiny antimalware and antivirus detected it immediately so it's of a no use.
My idea was to have a loader-like app (like I now have exe which is basically just loader for dlls, which can be dynamically updated while running...) but to never exploit the dll file itself, but to be able to dynamically load code inside of the loader process and execute it as needed. Cool feature would be to actually have a .jpeg or .bmp file which would hide the code I need to execute. Sounds like a virus, I know, but it wasnt.:D

Answer (score 1):

Just put program's path into a variable and call it using "&".

example:

```
$toRun = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

& $toRun
```

Comment: That's not what OP was asking. This executes the process by itself, on itself, from it's own working path.
The question here is how to sideload raw code into the existing memory of the process (in this example Powershell) and run it so that the code runs just as it would as separate process, but does not create separate process in reality and does not get allocated separate memory portion for itself. In other words, process runs but the OS is not aware of it. Perfect malware, but knowing and doing this is important for anti-malware as well.

Answer (score 0):

in other words you can :

$toRun = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Start-Process $torun

Comment: That's not what OP was asking. This executes the process by itself, on itself, from it's own working path.
The question here is how to sideload raw code into the existing memory of the process (in this example Powershell) and run it so that the code runs just as it would as separate process, but does not create separate process in reality and does not get allocated separate memory portion for itself. In other words, process runs but the OS is not aware of it. Perfect malware, but knowing and doing this is important for anti-malware as well.